# Slim Train API doesn't provide control to user to extract loss and accuracy metrics

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-slim

I am referring to [train_image_classifier.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/train_image_classifier.py) script provided by Tensorflow for image classification.

Script uses slim.learning.train API to kick off the training and then it takes care for everything internally.
My requirement is to extract loss and accuracy metrics after every n number of epochs, i.e. 5 and dump that into database for later analysis.

But because of high level abstraction of slim train API, it doesn't return loss/accuracy info.

Is there any way to tap the training process and get the loss/accuracy values after given number of steps/epochs ?
If it's possible, please share the pseudo code for that.

It will be really helpful for me.

Thanks.